# How to use compile_commands.json with clang python bindings?

Tags: python, c++, clang, clang++

I have the following script that attempts to print out all the AST nodes in a given C++ file. This works fine when using it on a simple file with trivial includes (header file in the same directory, etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
from clang import cindex


def node_info(node):
    return {'kind': node.kind,
            'usr': node.get_usr(),
            'spelling': node.spelling,
            'location': node.location,
            'file': node.location.file.name,
            'extent.start': node.extent.start,
            'extent.end': node.extent.end,
            'is_definition': node.is_definition()
            }


def get_nodes_in_file(node, filename, ls=None):
    ls = ls if ls is not None else []
    for n in node.get_children():
        if n.location.file is not None and n.location.file.name == filename:
            ls.append(n)
            get_nodes_in_file(n, filename, ls)
    return ls


def main():
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument('source_file', type=FileType('r+'),
                            help='C++ source file to parse.')
    arg_parser.add_argument('compilation_database', type=FileType('r+'),
                            help='The compile_commands.json to use to parse the source file.')
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    compilation_database_path = args.compilation_database.name
    source_file_path = args.source_file.name
    clang_args = ['-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-p', compilation_database_path]
    index = cindex.Index.create()
    translation_unit = index.parse(source_file_path, clang_args)
    file_nodes = get_nodes_in_file(translation_unit.cursor, source_file_path)
    print [p.spelling for p in file_nodes]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I get a `clang.cindex.TranslationUnitLoadError: Error parsing translation unit.` when I run the script and provide a valid C++ file that has a compile_commands.json file in its parent directory. This code runs and builds fine using CMake with clang, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the argument for pointing to the compile_commands.json correctly.

I also had difficulty finding this option in the clang documentation and could not get `-ast-dump` to work. However, clang-check works fine by just passing the file path!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your own accepted answer is incorrect. `libclang` [does support compilation databases](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__COMPILATIONDB.html) and [so does cindex.py](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/4ab9d6e02b29c24ca44638cc61b52cde2df4a888/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py#L2748), the libclang python binding.

The main source of confusion might be that the compilation flags that libclang knows/uses are only a subset of all arguments that can be passed to the clang frontend. The compilation database is supported but does not work automatically: it must be loaded and queried manually. Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from argparse import ArgumentParser, FileType
from clang import cindex

compilation_database_path = args.compilation_database.name
source_file_path = args.source_file.name
index = cindex.Index.create()

# Step 1: load the compilation database
compdb = cindex.CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory(compilation_database_path)

# Step 2: query compilation flags
try:
    file_args = compdb.getCompileCommands(source_file_path)
    translation_unit = index.parse(source_file_path, file_args)
    file_nodes = get_nodes_in_file(translation_unit.cursor, source_file_path)
    print [p.spelling for p in file_nodes]
except CompilationDatabaseError:
    print 'Could not load compilation flags for', source_file_path
```

Comment: What version of clang was this first introduced? When I wrote this question I was using clang 3.4 of both libclang and cindex.py.

Comment: No idea, but I'm pretty sure that at the time it was 3.8 already which had it for ages.

Comment: Looks like it's in 3.4 as well, must have missed it.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much, I'm sure that will help many people.

Comment: Thanks @static_rtti for the bounty and kind words.

Comment: @TamásSzelei : could you add imports to make your snippet easier to use?

Comment: @static_rtti Sure.

Comment: I think this way of creating the arguments has become deprecated. If anyone can update the answer to reflect the changes to the python API that would be awesome. I copy pasted this as is, and the file_args type seems incompatible with the expected type of the args parameter of the parsing method.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer seems to be deprecated, at minimum it did not work for me, I had to do this:

```
import clang.cindex


def main():
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

    compdb = clang.cindex.CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory(
        "dir/")

    source_file_path = 'path/to/file.cpp'
    commands = compdb.getCompileCommands(source_file_path)

    file_args = []
    for command in commands:
        for argument in command.arguments:
            file_args.append(argument)
    file_args = file_args[3:-3]
    print(file_args)
    translation_unit = index.parse(source_file_path, args=file_args)

    comment_tokens = GetDoxygenCommentTokens(translation_unit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Basically I had to iterate over the commands and the arguments to create a string, and then eliminate some g++ specific flags.

Comment: Worked on clang 16.0.1. The accepted answer reported error: `'CompileCommand' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: On OSX, the file_args shuld be treated carefully with `file_args = file_args[2:-4]`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Libclang does not support the compilation database but Libtooling does. To get around this I took the path to the `compile_commands.json` as an argument and ended up parsing it myself to find the file of interest and the relevant includes (the `-I` and `-isystem` includes).

Comment: My answer is not correct, please see the accepted answer.