# How to use compile_commands.json with llvm clang (version 7.0.1) python bindings?

Tags: python, c++, clang, llvm, libclang

I am attempting to print out all the AST nodes in a given C++ file. And i provide a valid C++ file that has a compile_commands.json file in its parent directory. All steps just like [How to use compile_commands.json with clang python bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652540/how-to-use-compile-commands-json-with-clang-python-bindings/38353410#38353410) and my clang version is: "clang version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin". OS is windows10, python version is 2.7. However, when i run this script below.

enter code here

```
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import *

libclang_path = r'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\libclang.dll'

if Config.loaded == True:
    pass
else:
    Config.set_library_file(libclang_path)


def node_info(node):
    return {'kind': node.kind,
            'usr': node.get_usr(),
            'spelling': node.spelling,
            'location': node.location,
            'file': node.location.file.name,
            'extent.start': node.extent.start,
            'extent.end': node.extent.end,
            'is_definition': node.is_definition()
            }


def get_nodes_in_file(node, filename, ls=None):
    ls = ls if ls is not None else []
    for n in node.get_children():
        if n.location.file is not None and n.location.file.name == filename:
            ls.append(n)
            get_nodes_in_file(n, filename, ls)
    return ls


def main():
    compilation_database_path = 'C:/Users/liqiu/Desktop/md/gn/build/win/x64'

    source_file_path = 'C:/Users/liqiu/Desktop/md/.../video_camera_source.cpp'

    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    compdb = clang.cindex.CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory(compilation_database_path)

    try:
        file_args = compdb.getCompileCommands(source_file_path)
        translation_unit = index.parse(source_file_path, file_args)
        file_nodes = get_nodes_in_file(translation_unit.cursor, source_file_path)
        print [p.spelling for p in file_nodes]
    except clang.cindex.CompilationDatabaseError:
        print 'Could not load compilation flags for', source_file_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are some errors like the following. I think the reason for this error is "file_args = compdb. GetCompileCommands (source_file_path)" this line returns a CompileCommand instance rather than string or integer type, so the index.parse（）can not directly accept this instance as a parameter. But this seems to have returned some string type of "Commands" in older versions of libclang. This caused me to be confused now.

```
D:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/liqiu/Desktop/libclang_parse/parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/liqiu/Desktop/libclang_parse/parser.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/liqiu/Desktop/libclang_parse/parser.py", line 43, in main
    translation_unit = index.parse(source_file_path, file_args)
  File "C:\Users\liqiu\Desktop\libclang_parse\clang\cindex.py", line 2689, in parse
    self)
  File "C:\Users\liqiu\Desktop\libclang_parse\clang\cindex.py", line 2783, in from_source
    args_array = (c_char_p * len(args))(*[b(x) for x in args])
TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of CompileCommand instance

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a listiterator,so we should handle like the following:

```
  file_args = compdb.getCompileCommands(source_file_path)
  arguments = list(iter(file_args).next().arguments)
```