# Python libclang how do you use a compilation database?

Tags: python, c++, libclang

This has been asked twice already one answer seems very popular:

[How to use compile_commands.json with clang python bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652540/how-to-use-compile-commands-json-with-clang-python-bindings)

This other one not as much:
[How to use compile_commands.json with llvm clang (version 7.0.1) python bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083241/how-to-use-compile-commands-json-with-llvm-clang-version-7-0-1-python-bindings)

However neither solution seems to work. If you try the most popular solution, i.e. if you do this:

```
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    compdb = clang.cindex.CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory('/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/build/')
    file_args = compdb.getCompileCommands(path)
    translation_unit = index.parse(path, file_args)
```

You will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/Source/../Scripts/notebook_generator.py", line 178, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/Source/../Scripts/notebook_generator.py", line 175, in main
    CreateNotebookFromHeader(args.path, args.out_path)
  File "/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/Source/../Scripts/notebook_generator.py", line 165, in CreateNotebookFromHeader
    nb['cells'] = GetHeaderCellPrototypes(path)
  File "/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/Source/../Scripts/notebook_generator.py", line 148, in GetHeaderCellPrototypes
    tokens = ExtractTokensOfInterest(path)
  File "/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/Source/../Scripts/notebook_generator.py", line 54, in ExtractTokensOfInterest
    translation_unit = index.parse(path, file_args)
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clang/cindex.py", line 2688, in parse
    return TranslationUnit.from_source(path, args, unsaved_files, options,
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clang/cindex.py", line 2783, in from_source
    args_array = (c_char_p * len(args))(*[b(x) for x in args])
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clang/cindex.py", line 2783, in <listcomp>
    args_array = (c_char_p * len(args))(*[b(x) for x in args])
  File "/home/makogan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clang/cindex.py", line 109, in b
    return x.encode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'CompileCommand' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

If you try the second option:

I.e. this:

```
print( list(iter(file_args).next().arguments))
```

You get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'iterator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

How are people getting that first solution to work for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way seems to be doing this:

```
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    token_dict = {}
    compdb = clang.cindex.CompilationDatabase.fromDirectory('/home/makogan/neverengine_personal/build/')
    commands = compdb.getCompileCommands(path)

    file_args = []
    for command in commands:
        for argument in command.arguments:
            file_args.append(argument)

    translation_unit = index.parse(path, file_args)
```